# Title animations on screen transition in custom Header component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have my own `Header` component that has a search field and some other features unique to my app. I simply define it on the `navigationOptions` for each screen.

```
SomeScreen.navigationOptions = (props) => ({
  header: <Header {... props} />,
});
```

What I want to do though is animate the title inside the  component itself as it moves from screen to screen? In general how can I accomplish this with a custom header? I've looked at the `react-navigation-stacks` implementation of Header but I can't make much sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of stack navigator, you'll need to check the props you receive. First of all, pass a function returning an element to the header option so that you receive the props:

```js
SomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  header: props => <Header {...props} />
};
```

---

If you're on `react-navigation-stack@2.x` (alpha), you get a prop called `scene`. It's an object containing a `progress` property which has 3 properties which are [reanimated](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-reanimated) nodes.

- `current`: represents the progress of the screen that the header, it ranges from 0 to 1, where 0 means the screen is fully hidden, and 1 means the screen is fully shown.
- `next`: similar to current, but for the next screen in the stack. can be `undefined` when there's no next screen
- `previous`: similar to current, but for the previous screen in the stack. can be `undefined` when there's no previous screen

You can interpolate on these values to animate your view. For example, say you want to animate the opacity to start from 0.5 and to 1 as screen comes in:

```js
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

// ...

<Animated.Text
  style={{
    opacity: Animated.interpolate(scene.progress.current, {
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0.5, 1]
    })
  }}
/>;
```

---

If you're on `react-navigation-stack@1.x`, you get a prop called `position`. It's an animated node which represents the current position of the stack (ranges from 0 to current index). You can [interpolate](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/animated#interpolation) on it to animate your header. It can be a bit tricky, so you'll have to play around.

For example, say you want to animate the opacity to start from 0.5 and to 1 as screen comes in:

> NOTE: I haven't tested this one so the code might be wrong. So you'll have to play around with it.

```js
import { Animated } from "react-native";

// ...

<Animated.Text
  style={{
    opacity: position.interpolate({
      inputRange: [index - 1, index],
      outputRange: [0.5, 1]
    })
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: That's what I was missing: the props for the header specifically being passed into my own component. I was looking for the `scene` variable and nwo I have it. Thanks!